# Search a column on Sheet name "Current" for a partial value and past the row once found on Sheet "Results

Tags: excel, vba

I'm trying to loop thru an excel sheet named "Current" in a column and look for any values that can partially match a value from a Userform. Once found it would copy that row and past it in the next empty row in Sheet "Results"

I've tried a few examples I've found here and tried to customize them but no luck. Here is the code I have now.

```
Option Explicit
Dim rng3 As Range
Dim Cell As Range

Sub CheckFutureSchedule()
Dim strSearch As String
strSearch = UserForm3.TextBox1.Text


With Sheets("Current")
Set rng3 = Range("D:D").Find(strSearch, , xlValues, xlPart)
        If Not rng3 Is Nothing Then
       .Rows(Cell.Row).Copy Destination:=Sheets("Results").Rows(Cell.Row)

   End If
   End With
   Worksheets("Results").Select
Unload UserForm3

End Sub
```

I'm not getting any errors just a blank sheet.

Comment: CheckFutureSchedule is called from UserForm3 button.

Comment: Change line to be:   .Rows(rng3.Cells.Row).Copy Destination:=Sheets("Results").Rows(rng3.Cells.Row)

Comment: I decided to add an ELSE in the IF statement with a Msgbox. The box is popping letting me know that rng3 is nothing.

Comment: Perhaps back up one more step, and add a Msgbox right after getting strSearch, and look at its length for any leading/trailing blanks, nulls, etc stuff we don't expect.  In my test, after I changed the line .Rows....I did not have a UserForm but just plugged in a known value for strSearch.

Comment: @donPablo I figured it out #facepalm the code is correct and so was the msgbox… the value truly wasn't found. On the positive, I found data that was incorrect in my other sheet lol. Thanks for your help. the code changes you suggested worked.

Answer (score 0):

I went with this, I got results but I know it can be simplified.

```
Sub SearchSchedule()
Worksheets("Current").Activate
strSearch = UserForm3.TextBox12.Text
lastrow = "D" & Range("D" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row

Dim Rng As Range
Set Rng = Range([D1], lastrow)
With Rng
.AutoFilter , field:=1, Criteria1:=strSearch
.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible).EntireRow.Copy
Application.Wait (Now + TimeValue("0:00:01"))

Worksheets("Results").Activate
Range("A1").Select
ActiveSheet.Paste
ActiveSheet.Columns.AutoFit

End With
```